# Putlocker PHP link parser

Tags: php, parsing, video, file-get-contents

so I've been working on a script for a while now and can't figure out one thing. For the site putlocker.com I want to generate a unique url for videos. So essentially it takes a standared url and from that I generate a direct url. I already post data and generate another link, in the new page there is another link that is the actual video link. However, this URL changes with every IP Address. The only way I figured it would work is to load the $search2url in an iframe and get the source of the iframe which I can then parse. However, I realized that this is not possible because it is not on my domain. If there is a way I can do that or any other way I can load the $search2url and parse the unique link please let me know. Thanks!

If you run the script on a server and try to play the video, the video won't play. However, if you go to the link from the start the video plays.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.putlocker.com/file/2CE47CB3D2292208";

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$find = strpos($contents, '<input type="hidden" value="');

$part1 = substr($contents, $find+28);
$hash = substr($part1, 0, strpos($part1, '"'));


$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'hash' => $hash,
        'confirm' => 'submitButton'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$url1 = substr($result, strpos($result, "/get_file.php?"));
$url2 = substr($url1, 0, strpos($url1, "'"));
$search2url = "http://www.putlocker.com$url2";
$res2 = file_get_contents($search2url);
$firstfinal1 = substr($res2, strpos($res2, 'url="')+5);
$finalmediaurl = substr($firstfinal1, 0, strpos($firstfinal1, '"'));
//echo $finalmediaurl;
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with put locker, but what do you mean by " this URL changes with every IP Address"?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra, I mean that from one IP address the video streams from a certain link, for another the link changes. The link changes with the IP. So the only way to get the unique link is to actually load the page from that users computer.

Comment: Ok gotcha, someone else may chime in first,  but let me think on this.